# How to route an array of params in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I want to pass through an array of params to a "testers" route in Rails. My table for testers currently looks like this:

```
class CreateTesters < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :testers do |t|
      t.integer :testerID
      t.string :firstName
      t.string :lastName
      t.string :country
      t.datetime :lastLogin

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The url I want to make a request to looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/testers?tester_id[]=1&tester_id[]=2&country[]=US`

My server is correctly identifying that I've passed an array of params, but my issue is that it's hitting the `index` route and simply returning all the testers in my database.

How do I either get Rails to recognize this as a 'show` request, or create a custom route for this type of url?

Comment: that's not the traditional `show` url, share your routes

Comment: My routes are currently just the standard routes, should I be adding a custom one here?

Comment: yes..what you want to show? 2 testers since you passing 2 ids?

Comment: Ideally I would want to show every tester that matches the ids I've passed in, so it could be a large amount. What would be the best way to accomplish this in your view?

Comment: Assuming that that URL is exactly what you want, you don't really want to "recognize this as a show request". At the same time, I suggest not to "create a custom route for this type of url". But rather, I suggest you still use the `index` action for this, but filter the returned data accordingly. i.e in `index` method: `@testers = params[:tester_id].present? ? Tester.where(id: params[:tester_id]) : Tester.all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comments, ideal of doing it is using your `index` action itself..

```
def index
  @testers = Tester.data(params[:tester_ids])
end
```

In your `testers.rb` model

```
scope :data, ->(ids) { ids.present? ? where(id: params[:tester_ids].split(',')) : all }
```

and your url will look like

`http://localhost:3000/testers` for all and

`http://localhost:3000/testers?tester_ids=1,2,3` for filtered testers

Answer (score 0):

In the view:

```
= link_to 'Testers', testers_path(ids: @selected_testers.pluck(:id))
```

In the controller:

```
@testers = Tester.find(params[:ids])
```

As opposed to using `where`, `find` makes sure that there's a record for every given ID. So if an ID 1337 comes in as part of the `params[:ids]` array and there is no tester with ID 1337 in the database, it raises an an error (similar to when you call `Tester.find(1337)`).